# Snow flake symmetry and angle of water molecule

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, water, crystals

I read in various places (e.g. Feynman Lectures) that the bonding angle of water molecules (ca 105 degrees) is related to the 6-fold symmetry of snow flakes.

I understand that in ice, the water molecules are arranged in a lattice, but how does the angle of 105 degrees match the interior angles of a hexagon (120 degrees)?

Do the water molecules in a lattice distort their angles to 120 degrees or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happen to the bonding angle of each individual water molecule in the ice. The bonding angle is still about 105 degrees. What really happen is the crystal structure of the ice is that since the intermolecular force between water molecules in ice crystal is hydrogen bonding, each water molecule would connect with 4 other molecules (as is shown in the following figure), similar to the connection relationship among carbon atoms in hexagonal dimand.[image]

There are over 18 different crystal structures of ice, among them the most common one is Ice-Ih, which is a hexagonal system.

The schematic of the crystal cell of this kind of crystal structure of ice is shown in the following figure.[image]
The arrangement of water molecules in this hexagonal crystal structure is similar to hexagonal diamond.

Please look up the following website for the hexagonal structure of ice if my discription is not clear enough.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Ih

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the reason is basically because the six water molecules forming a hexagon are not lying in a plane?

Comment: I think you understood it correctly. The six water molecules forming a hexagon are not lying in a plane, similar to the six carbon atoms in a hexamethylene molecule. I think you can imagine water molecules in ice crystal as carbon atoms.